# How to sum same array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I want to sum array in same key and different value.

```
Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'locker_id' => 3,
            'locker_model' => 1,
            'qty' => 2
        ),

1 => Array
    (
        'locker_id' => 3,
        'locker_model' => 1,
        'qty' => 1
    ),

2 => Array
    (
        'locker_id' => 2,
        'locker_model' => 1,
        'qty' => 2
    ),

 3 => Array
    (
        'locker_id' => 3,
        'locker_model' => 1,
        'qty' => 2
    ),
4 => Array
    (
        'locker_id' => 2,
        'locker_model' => 1,
        'qty' => 2
    )

);
```

I want Output it

```
Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'locker_id' => 3,
            'locker_model' => 1,
            'qty' => 5
        ),
1 => Array
    (
        'locker_id' => 2,
        'locker_model' => 1,
        'qty' => 4
    )
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: From your description it is hard to tell what you are trying to do. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I think "locker_id" should be "2" in the 2nd key of 2nd array

Answer (score 2):

You could browse your array while creating a new one with keys like "locker_id-locker_model", then you can easily check if your locker exists in this array with array_key_exists function.

```
$inputArray = array( ... ); // this is your message array
$outputArray = array();

foreach( $inputArray as $locker )
{
    if( !array_key_exists( $locker["locker_id"]."-".$locker["locker_model"], $outputArray ) )
    {
        $outputArray[ $locker["locker_id"]."-".$locker["locker_model"] ] = array(
            "locker_id" => $locker["locker_id"],
            "locker_model" => $locker["locker_model"],
            "qty" => 0
        );
    }

    $outputArray[ $locker["locker_id"]."-".$locker["locker_model"] ]["qty"]++;
}

var_dump( $outputArray );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $dataArr = array
    (
        0 => array
            (
                'locker_id' => 3,
                'locker_model' => 1,
                'qty' => 2
            ),

        1 => array
            (
                'locker_id' => 3,
                'locker_model' => 1,
                'qty' => 1
            ),

        2 => array
            (
                'locker_id' => 2,
                'locker_model' => 1,
                'qty' => 2
            ),

         3 => array
            (
                'locker_id' => 3,
                'locker_model' => 1,
                'qty' => 2
            ),
        4 => array
            (
                'locker_id' => 2,
                'locker_model' => 1,
                'qty' => 2
            )

    );

    $sumArr = array();
    if(count($dataArr)>0){
        foreach($dataArr as $data){

            if(!isset($sumArr[$data['locker_id']])){
                $sumArr[$data['locker_id']] = $data;
            }
            $sumArr[$data['locker_id']]['qty'] +=$data['qty'];
        }
    }
  echo "<pre>";print_r($sumArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();  

foreach($array as $key => $value){
  if(isset($value['locker_id'])){
     $result[$value['locker_id']]['qty'] += $value['qty'];
  }
  else{
     $result[$value['locker_id']] = $value;
  }

}
```

You have to loop over your array and save it to another let's say $result. In $result you should put the locker_id as key and then you only have to verify if that key exists. If it is you add the qty value, if isn't you have to add the entire new item.

Comment: Your answer would be much more useful if it explained how it works and how it answers the question. That way the asker learns more than if they just copy your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Considering $array1 is your first array,

```
$array2 = array();
foreach($array1 as $k=>$v) {
    if(!isset($array2[$v['locker_id']])) {
        $array2[$v['locker_id']] = $v;
    } else {
        $array2[$v['locker_id']]['qty'] += $v['qty'];
    }
}

print_r($array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
$arr is your array

```
$j = 0;
$new = array();
$new[0][qty];

for($i=0;$i<arraylength;$i++){
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
if($arr[$i][lockerid] == $arr[$key][lockerid]) {
$new[$j][lockerid] = $arr[$key][lockerid];
$new[$j][lockermodel] = $arr[$key][lockermodel];
$new[$j][qty] = $new[$i][qty] + $arr[$key][qty];
J++;
}
}
}
```

Comment: What does $new[0][qty]; line mean?

Comment: remove that it will work without that also.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$ARR_OUTPUT = array();

    // $arr will contains your input array
    foreach($arr as $arr_val)
    {
       $locker_id = $arr_val['locker_id'];
       $locker_model = $arr_val['locker_id'];
       $qty = $arr_val['locker_id'];



       if(isset($ARR_OUTPUT[$locker_id][$locker_model]))
       {    
            $ARR_OUTPUT[$locker_id][$locker_model] += $qty;
       }
       else
       {
            $ARR_OUTPUT[$locker_id][$locker_model] = $qty;
       }



        }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($ARR_OUTPUT);

$ARR_OUTPUT2 = array();

    foreach($ARR_OUTPUT as $locker_id=>$arr_values)
    {
        foreach($arr_values as $locker_model=>$qty)
        {
            $arr_temp['locker_id'] = $locker_id;
            $arr_temp['locker_model'] = $locker_model;
            $arr_temp['qty'] = $qty;
            $ARR_OUTPUT2[] = $arr_temp;
        }   
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($ARR_OUTPUT2);
```